# Mark own answer as blog post

Tags: feature-request, answers, profile-page

Stack Overflow is my main web environment. Of course I've got several social media accounts, but if you want to know me *professionally*, Stack Overflow is the place, even more than LinkedIn. I don't have a blog page. But in fact, I do blog. Some of my SO answers have grown into blogs. I return to them frequently to keep them up-to-date, and I refer to them in other answers or duplicates.

However, I can't refer other people to my blog portfolio. Of course, this is entirely my fault, but still here's my question. What do you think of an option to mark your own answers as "blog", so they are easily accessible from your profile page? Maybe as an extra tab "Blogs" besides  "All/ Questions/Answers"?

[image]

Another reason why I'd really like this is that when I see a great answer I'm curious to the user's other answers. But often there are so many of them... I'd love her/him to make a selection for me.

Comment: Shog9 posted a related suggestion here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252711/135615 as something that could be a 30k user privilege.

Comment: Do we really want to encourage people to use SO as a blogging platform?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan No, let's keep encouraging people to write great answers. If they turn out to look like great blogs, who complains?

Comment: I think referring them as Blogs is what I'm having a problem with. Maybe "Best Posts" or something like that would be more in line with what SO is about...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Ah, OK, yeah, maybe it's not the best wording. I'm in for anything that makes it more appropriate for SO.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you want to create an SO careers profile.  It has the ability to show others the SO posts of yours that you feel are notable.

Comment: I know, and I already did. But that's a different audience and I'd like to bring it together.

Comment: @GertArnold You can have a list of links in your profile, if that's your target audience.

Comment: That could be an alternative for me personally. I can't ask others to do that though. Making it part of the site's tooling would be more inviting I think.

Comment: @GertArnold It is a part of the site's tooling, through Careers, you just don't want to use that to do this.

Comment: No really, I would if it would be a perfect fit. But at careers I tend to show other answers (more broad and architecture-focussed) than I would at SO (more technically driven and aimed at recurring problems developers experience).

Comment: I wouldn't mind to add a link to my careers page in my profile though.

Comment: @GertArnold If you just want to link people reading your profile to questions of yours that you think they would think are interesting, then linking them in your profile is the way to do that.  It's a perfectly acceptable solution to the problem that needs nothing more implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Someone created a WordPress plugin that you can use to turn your SE posts into blog posts here: https://stackapps.com/questions/3237/stacktack-wordpress-plugin-embed-stack-exchange-questions-in-your-blog

Comment: Maybe useful. But that's my question upside-down. I'm not looking for a place to copy answers to, with or without helpful tools.